# Extracting data using ajax from a database in django and then display it in view

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

How should I extract data from a database using ajax in Django and display it in view in the form of charts. I wanna select items from dropdown options and then display those selected data in the webpage in the form of charts.

Can anyone please guide me in this.

My codes are:
index.html:

```
<div class="row">
                      <form class="form-row" action="{{ }}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control select2" > 
                          <option>Select Major Head</option>
                          {% for major in majors %}
                            <option value="{{ major.pk }}">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description } </option> 
                          {% endfor %} 
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Display">
                      </div>
                      </form>
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
<div class="card-body" >
                <div id="chart">
                  <embed type="image/svg+xml" src= {{ chart|safe }} />
               </div>
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
majors = Major.objects.filter(percentages__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("pk")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.POST.get('be_nextyr_total')

    line_chart = pygal.Line(width=1500)
    line_chart.title = 'Budget Estimation'
context = { 
        "chart": line_chart.render_data_uri(),
        'majors': majors
    }
    return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )
```

charts.js

```
$('form').on('Display',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : $(this).attr('action'),
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        success  : function(data) {
            // $(".printArea").empty().append(data).css('visibility','visible');
            return data;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Where do you want to display data in `django view` or `html template`?

Comment: Does this answer your question [django-js-how-to-post-a-form-without-reloading-whole-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65052844/django-js-how-to-post-a-form-without-reloading-whole-page/65057658)?

Comment: Hi , instead of `Display` use `submit` in your event handler and there is no inputs with name `be_nextyr_total` ..in your html code .

Comment: @AjayLingayat Thank you. It helped me. But I still have a doubt what i should put in the parameter of onclick button <button type="button" onclick="submitData({{ ????? }})">Submit</button>

Comment: @Swati Thank you. I have now used Submit in my event handler

Comment: @jas If you require any value to be passed inside the function then pass the parameter. Otherwise just call the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @AjayLingayat