# How to store information from javascript into a Django model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I currently have an app which uses HTML/CSS/JQuery. As of right now all my data is saved in Jquery (and therefore not saved between sessions), but I am learning Django and want to learn how I would save that JQuery data into Django models. So how do javascript and django communicate in order to save information from one to the other?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: You can save the information using Ajax. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65057658/12132509