# How to call a django function on click that doesn't involve changing page

Tags: django

**I would like to have a simple task:**

- When I click a button in the **Template** a function in the **Views** is called.

I know I should make a url but I don't want the page to reload when the button is clicked

I read something about AJAX/jQuery & I wonder if there is any alternatives that is limited to django and python?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django/Js: how to post a form without reloading whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65052844/django-js-how-to-post-a-form-without-reloading-whole-page)

Comment: I think it looks fair enough, I will work with it.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello,
I have read the answer & I believe it makes sense indeed.
I am just in the view section and I wonder is all of this code a boilerplate code that I must include or was it specific for the question?
Like, I only want to pass parameters: request, id & size. and then write my own logic so what should I cross out from the views.py section answer.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The id was required in that answer i.e i passed it u can ignore it and just send a request without id. In view u can write ur own logic but you have to return a jsonresponse if want to get any response data from the view in ur html page.

Comment: Got you, Thanks a lot!